# Laravel queue running on supervisor redis

Tags: laravel, redis, supervisord

I am having a hard time figuring out why it's not running in supervisor but works fine when running it on project.

When I try to run

> php artisan queue:work redis

on my project and it returns

[image]

but if I run it via supervisor, I getting this log

[image]

this is my laravel-worker program name inside /etc/supervisor/conf.d

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: See the database to find out what the error is on `failed_jobs` table.

Comment: thank you for your response @matiaslauriti but im running it via redis-server

Comment: I am not sure if you can run with `--vvv` and show the errors, try that.

Comment: why not use [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon) then run `supervisor`

Comment: will try that thanks @Doggo

Answer (score 0):

I see that supervisor will launch 8 worker processes that is different from running 1 process in first way.
You can try specify numprocs = 1, if it works.
Please check the code logic.

Comment: will try this, appreciate it!